# Flicking pages when navigating between pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So i have researched a lot but did not come to conclusion.

I am using a library for scrolling in two of my pages, i am using react-router here is the code in app.js :

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./Views/About";
import Contact from "./Views/Contact";
import Home from "./Views/Home";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer";
import Projects from "./Views/Projects";

function App() {
  return (

    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Home />} path="/" />
        <Route element={<About />} path="/about" />
        <Route element={<Contact />} path="/contact" />
        <Route element={<Projects />} path="/projects" />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and my home page code is this :

```
import React from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import InfoSection from "../Components/InfoSection";
import CardInfo from "../Components/CardInfo.js";
import {
  Animator,
  ScrollContainer,
  ScrollPage,
  batch,
  Fade,
  FadeIn,
  FadeOut,
  Move,
  MoveIn,
  MoveOut,
  Sticky,
  StickyIn,
  StickyOut,
  Zoom,
  ZoomIn,
  ZoomOut,
} from "react-scroll-motion";

function Home() {
  return (
    <ScrollContainer>
      <ScrollPage>
        <Animator animation={batch(Fade(), Sticky(), MoveOut(0, -200))}>
          <span className="topicParagraph-font" style={{ fontSize: "50px" }}>
            CONTRAIN TECHNOLOGIES
          </span>
        </Animator>
      </ScrollPage>
      <ScrollPage>
        <Animator animation={batch(StickyIn(), FadeIn(), ZoomIn())}>
          <span className="topicParagraph-font" style={{ fontSize: "40px" }}>
            WELCOME
          </span>
        </Animator>
      </ScrollPage>
      <ScrollPage>
        <Animator animation={batch(Fade(), Move(), Sticky())}>
          <span className="topicParagraph-font" style={{ fontSize: "40px" }}>
            TO THE ROBOTIC WORLD
          </span>
        </Animator>
      </ScrollPage>
      <ScrollPage>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            height: "100%",
          }}
        >
          <span className="topicParagraph-font" style={{ fontSize: "40px" }}>
            - THE CONTRAIN TEAM -
            <Animator animation={MoveIn(-1000, 0)}>JOEL SPOLEN</Animator>
            <Animator animation={MoveIn(1000, 0)}>MAHDI KAMANKESH</Animator>
            <Animator animation={MoveOut(1000, 0)}>WALTHER ERICSSON</Animator>
            <Animator animation={MoveOut(-1000, 0)}>JILL SPOLEN</Animator>
          </span>
        </div>
      </ScrollPage>
      <ScrollPage>
        <Animator animation={batch(Fade(), Sticky())}>
          <span style={{ fontSize: "40px" }}>WELCOME AGAIN</span>
          <br />
          <span className="topicParagraph-font" style={{ fontSize: "30px" }}>
            WE ARE CREATING ROBOTICS HANDS
          </span>
        </Animator>
      </ScrollPage>
      <InfoSection />
      <ScrollPage>
        <Animator animation={batch(Fade(), Move(), Sticky())}>
          <span className="topicParagraph-font" style={{ fontSize: "40px" }}>
            <CardInfo />
          </span>
        </Animator>
      </ScrollPage>
      <div style={{ height: "60vh" }}></div>
      <InfoSection />
      <ScrollPage>
        <Animator animation={batch(Fade(), Move(), Sticky())}>
          <span className="topicParagraph-font" style={{ fontSize: "40px" }}>
            <CardInfo />
          </span>
        </Animator>
      </ScrollPage>
      <div style={{ height: "60vh" }}></div>
    </ScrollContainer>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

My home page is flicking when i navigate back to the home page , does anyone have a solution for this ? Thanks

Comment: You need to understand why it's flicking, try removing all the content from home page for debugging purposes and test if it's flicking, if yes, the problem is in some useEffect which is called in the application

Comment: I have already done it , so the flicking problem only occurs when i am using the "react-scroll-motion" library , but i dont know how to solve it. @Alopwer

Comment: Can you please create a demo in codesandbox? I'll try to help you

Comment: or just share you application via github and ngrok proxy server, it will be easier to test it

Comment: Absolutely 
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-dan-uw3v7x?file=/src/Home.js
When you navigate back to home , you will see flicking. @Alopwer

Comment: For me I see flicking only when navigating to about us page

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-dan-uw3v7x?file=/src/CardInfo.js
it is updated now so you can check it , about us page and home page flicking if you expand the screen, Thanks ! @Alopwer

Comment: it's not working now)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-dan-uw3v7x?file=/src/Home.js
is it working now ?

Comment: Yes, it's working, but I can't find the solution, I think it's linked to some css issues + Fade() and these kind of functions, good luck

Comment: The problem was the library itself , i used the library without react router but it still flickered.